# What do employers think of LinkedIn Learning coding certificates?

Tags: resume, job-search

I have a graduate-level mathematics background but little coding skill sets, which has led to me getting many interviews but no job offers.

I recently heard of LinkedIn Learning, formerly Lynda.com, which provides great online training, according to my school's career resources center.  However, one has to pay for this training -- they're not free tutorials.

How would my resume be perceived, if I documented my LinkedIn Learning progression, say, with the Python language and its libraries such as NumPy and Pandas?  Will it give my resume a strong boost?

(I'm still deciding on whether I will sign up for the training ...)

Comment: Don't sign up with Lynda. You will regret it if you do.

Comment: The questions are. Do you know how to code? Do you have a project portfolio? What if any CS-related courses have you taken? And what jobs are you applying for?

Comment: It's best to cherry-pick your courses. There isn't one source that's best for all technical courses. Try Udacity and Coursera first (do not sign up for their trial, just register your email address with them). Many of their courses are free and high quality. Then try Udemy. They have very cheap courses. Look for sales. If you just need to brush up on a language's syntax. Try sololearn on your phone.  Also, read up on Space Repetition Learning for learning how to program, which should lead you to Anki.

Answer (score 7):

It may help bolster the resume slightly - but I don't see it making a huge difference. If I saw it on a submitted resume I doubt I'd give it much more weight than saying "well they are obviously keen", it wouldn't say much about your technical skill level.

That said I think you might be looking at this from the wrong angle, you say in the question:

> getting many interviews but no job offers

So I don't think your *resume* is the problem - clearly it's getting you in the door but you aren't able to convert the interview to an offer. So you need to have a look at where that could be going wrong, this may be that your interview technique isn't great (not having a dig - I'm godawful in interviews and always have been!) or it maybe that your skillset isn't quite up to snuff.

If it's the latter than more training/learning is going to be a good thing to do - and while you don't have job experience to put on the CV you may as well document any completed courses there.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually two parts of your question.

**Part #1 - Resume Perception**

One thing a lot of people lose sight of: anything like credentials, github repos, coding portfolios, etc - is simply used as a proxy of "Can this person do the job?"

In other words, if we get an applicant with a github repo that has a decent amount of code or has a .NET Microsoft certification, we're not excited about the specific accomplishments.  We're excited because it's a decent indicator that they're capable of doing the job we need.

Once you understand that, the problem becomes much simpler: what things can you do to let employers know that you have coding proficiency?  Github's a great one, which potential employers love (since they can go ahead and poke around with how you typically code.)  So if you're worried about lynda being expensive, or anything like that - just start doing some coding projects and putting them into GitHub.

**Part #2 - Actual Skills**

This is going to sound mean, but I'm pretty sure your problem is *not* that your resume is being perceived badly.  I mean, you're getting the interviews... its only when you come in and meet with them that they say "Yeah, that's not who we're going to hire."  Your problem is... you don't have the skills needed for the job.

Which isn't the end of the world.  Get the skills you want - heck, there are all sorts of 'learn to program' channels on YouTube alone.

The main reason I bring this up is... I'm a bit worried from the tenor of your question.  You didn't ask anything about "What's the best way of learning X, Y, and Z?"  Everything was from the lens of "How can I make myself look good to companies?"  I'd suggest worrying more about getting those skills in the first place.

Comment: *You didn't ask anything about "What's the best way of learning X, Y, and Z?"* Wouldn't that be off-topic, especially since the X, Y, and Z here aren't about management or HR skills?

Comment: Off topic here?  Maybe.  Off topic at stackoverflow?  Probably not, though I bet the question's already been asked+answered there multiple times.

Comment: That question is absolutely off-topic on Stack Overflow as it is opinion based and would also likely be seen as a request for off site resources. Better off asking in one of the chat rooms.

Comment: Might be on topic for the cseducators StackExchange site.